# How to send a liste of choise to another page in VisualForce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a page with a list of Asset.
In this list, i have one checkbox by Asset.
I'm trying to open another page with my selection.
I create a object with all selected Asset.
When i try to give my object to my new page, i have the message "Attempt to de-reference a null object".
Do you have some idea to how correct this?

My first page:

```
<apex:page Controller="CreationProjetController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="Créer" action="{!newProject}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Actif sans projet" id="creationprojet_list">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! Asset }" var="a">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!a.selected}" id="idSelected"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{! a.Asset.Id }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! a.Asset.Status }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! a.Asset.AccountId }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! a.Asset.Name }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! a.Asset.Contrat_Standard__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! a.Asset.D_partement_du_compte__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! a.Asset.Projet__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! a.Asset.Date_intervention__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! a.Asset.CreatedDate }"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

My Controller

```
public class CreationProjetController {
    private String sortOrder = 'AccountId';
    public List<cAsset> assetList {get;set;}
    public string compte;
    public boolean unCompte = true;
    public string contrat;
    public boolean unContrat = true;

    //Populer notre collection d'objet
    public List<cAsset> getAsset(){
        assetList = new List<cAsset>();
        //Requête pour récuperer les objet
        for(Asset a :[SELECT Id, Status, Name, AccountId, Contrat_Standard__c, D_partement_du_compte__c, Projet__c, Date_intervention__c, CreatedDate 
                      FROM Asset 
                      WHERE (  
                          (Status LIKE 'Acheté') AND
                          Contrat_Standard__c <> NULL AND
                          Projet__c = NULL AND
                          (NOT Name LIKE '%licence%') AND (NOT Name LIKE 'Facturation specifique') AND 
                          (NOT Status LIKE 'Sans BDC') AND (NOT Status LIKE '%Opportunité%') 
                      ) 
                      ORDER BY AccountId ASC LIMIT 1000]){
                          assetList.add(new cAsset(a));
                    }
        return assetList;
    }
    public class cAsset{
        public Asset asset {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public cAsset(Asset a){
            asset = a;
            selected = false;
        }               
    }

    public SelectedAsset getSelectedAsset(){
        SelectedAsset selectedwrpList = new SelectedAsset(assetList);
        return selectedwrpList;
    }

    public class SelectedAsset{
        public List<Asset> assetChoise{get;set;}
        public string compte; 
        public string contrat;
        public boolean unContrat = true; 
        public boolean unCompte = true;

        public SelectedAsset(List<cAsset> assetList){
            compte = assetList.get(0).asset.AccountId;
            contrat = assetList.get(0).asset.Contrat_Standard__c;

            for(cAsset a :assetList){
                if (a.selected = true){
                    if(a.asset.Contrat_Standard__c != contrat){
                        unContrat =  false;
                    }
                    if(a.asset.AccountId != compte){
                        unCompte =  false;
                    }
                    assetChoise.add(a.asset); 
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    public PageReference newProject() {
        SelectedAsset assetChoise = new SelectedAsset(assetList);
        PageReference newProject = new pagereference('/Apex/CreationProjet2');
        newProject.setRedirect(false);  
        return newProject;
    } 
}
```

My second page:

```
<apex:page Controller="CreationProjetController" >
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Actif selectionné" id="creationprojet_list">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!assetChoise}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{! a.id }"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What does the controller on the second page look like? I also don't see you passing an parameters to the second page.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the "wizard" approach to VF pages, where same controller is reused on mutliple pages and that's how state is being passed. Good, this should work OK, it's documented https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm for example.

Check this piece:

```
SelectedAsset assetChoise = new SelectedAsset(assetList);
PageReference newProject = new pagereference('/Apex/CreationProjet2');
```

Page 2 references a variable that doesn't exist in controller. You've just made a local variable with that name. Try to either reference original `assetList` in your 2nd page or make `assetChoise` a full class-level variable, not just a local in this method.

And try to create the pagereference as `Page.CreationProjet2`, not as strings. Like in that wizard demo. No idea if it changes anything in your bug but it's genrally better idea. That way page is really referenced in code and for example SF will warn you when you try to delete the page, it'll throw error about usage in this class. If it was just a string/address reference it'd happily let you delete and only user would see the error during testing...